# Racket RPN Validator

Tags: scheme, racket

I am currently trying to create a Reverse Polish Notation program in racket. I want to have 6 numbers and 5 operators.Numbers are represented by -1 in the list while operators are represented as 1's in the list.

In the code below I can get all permutations of the list with no duplicates. I add two -1's at the front of the list and a one 1 at the end this is because for valid RPN it needs to have two numbers at the start and one operator at the end.

```
;This our original list to create reverse polish notation -1 will represent operators
;and 1 will represent numbers. It doesnt have two -1's and one 1 because for valid
;reverse polish notaion it needs to start with two nummbers and end with an operator
(define start-perm (list -1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1))

;This line creates all permutations of the original RPN list and it removes the duplicates 
(define perms (remove-duplicates (permutations start-perm)))

;This function adds the two 1s to the front of the list and the -1 to the end of the list 
(define (make-rpn l)
 (append (list 1 1) l (list -1)))

(make-rpn (car  perms))
; adds 1 1 to start of all permutations and adds -1 to the end of all permutations
(map make-rpn perms)
```

The problem I have is I cant output only valid RPN. Through research it seems that a stack is the best approach but I cant seem to get it implemented into this code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest possible solution is probably reversing the input and passing it to a recursive descent parser for (regular) Polish Notation:

```
(define (validate rpn)
  (define/match (go pn)
    [(`(1  . ,rest)) rest]
    [(`(-1 . ,rest)) (let ([rest^ (go rest)])
                       (and rest^ (go rest^)))]
    [(else) #f])
  (null? (go (reverse rpn))))
```

(As an aside, it would be clearer to use symbols, say 'num and 'op, instead of 1 and -1.)